# T-SQL - remove chars from string beginning from specific character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

from table I retrieves values, for example,

```
7752652:1,7752653:2,7752654:3,7752655:4
```

or

```
7752941:1,7752942:2
```

i.e. string may contain any quantity of substrings. 
What I need: remove all occurrences of characters from char ':' to a comma char. 
For example,

```
7752652:1,7752653:2,7752654:3,7752655:4
```

should be

```
7752652,7752653,7752654,7752655
```

How do it?

Comment: Can we assume that the numbers (both before and after the colon) can be different lengths?

Comment: Cross apply on a split function, remove the stuff after the `:` then feed all that into XML PATH to reassemble the string. Or just use CLR and regular expressions replace.

Comment: If I had a penny for each comma separated value SQL question... anyway, what do you mean by "remove"? Remove from the field as in updating the original data, or just select the values with the values removed in the result?

Comment: Though actually split functions are just procedural code so might as well just write a scalar function that does the split and string concatenation directly and returns the reassembled string.

Comment: this values already participate in outer apply, so I need to make replacements "on the fly"

Comment: If a query is being used to generate this list, you can probably modify that query.  If not, you should learn not to store comma delimited fields in string fields in a table.  Learn to use junction tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with CLR function. It is more quickly and function can be used in complex queries

```
public static SqlString fnRemoveSuffics(SqlString source)
{
    string pattern = @":(\d+)";
    string replacement = "";
    string result = Regex.Replace(source.Value, pattern, replacement);

    return new SqlString(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `:` with start tag `<X>`.
Replace `,` with end tag `</X>` and an extra comma.
Add an extra end tag to the end `</X>`.

That will give you a string that look like `7752941<X>1</X>,7752942<X>2</X>`.

Cast to XML and use `query(text())` to get the root text values.
Cast the result back to string.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/71fd0/1)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
create table T
(
  C varchar(100)
)

insert into T values
('7752652:1,7752653:2,7752654:3,7752655:4'),
('7752941:1,7752942:2')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select cast(cast(replace(replace(T.C, ':', '<X>'), ',', '</X>,')+'</X>' as xml).query('text()') as varchar(100)) as C
from T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/71fd0/1/0)**:

```
|                               C |
|---------------------------------|
| 7752652,7752653,7752654,7752655 |
|                 7752941,7752942 |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @query varchar(8000)
select @query= 'select '+ replace (
            replace('7752652:1,7752653:2,7752654:3,7752655:4',',',' t union all select ')
            ,':',' t1 , ')
exec(';with cte as ( '+@query+' ) select cast(t1 as varchar)+'','' from cte for xml path('''')')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Data VARCHAR(100) = '7752652:1,7752653:2,7752654:3,7752655:4'
DECLARE @Output VARCHAR(100) = ''

WHILE CHARINDEX(':', @Data) > 0
BEGIN
    IF LEN(@Output) > 0 SET @Output = @Output + ','
    SET @Output = @Output + LEFT(@Data, CHARINDEX(':', @Data)-1)

    SET @Data = STUFF(@Data, 
                      1,  
                      (CASE CHARINDEX(',', @Data) 
                            WHEN 0 THEN LEN(@Data) 
                            ELSE CHARINDEX(',', @Data) 
                            END) - CHARINDEX(':', @Data),
                       '')
END

SELECT @Output AS Result -- 7752652,7752653,7752654,7752655
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

I borrowed the Splitter function from [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1665/sql-server-clr-and-tsql-functions-to-parse-a-delimited-string/). You could use any delimiter parser you may already be using.

1. Parse the string to table values
2. Used Substring function to remove values after ':'
3. Use For xml to re-generate CSV

**Test Data:**'

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#temp')>0
DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp (id int, StringCSV VARCHAR(500))
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('1','7752652:1,7752653:2,7752654:3,7752655:4')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('2','7752656:1,7752657:3,7752658:4')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('3','7752659:1,7752660:2')
SELECT * FROM #temp t
```

**Main Query:**

```
;WITH cte_Remove(ID, REMOVE) AS 
(
    SELECT   y.id   AS ID,
             SUBSTRING(fn.string, 1, CHARINDEX(':', fn.string) -1) AS Removed
    FROM     #temp  AS y
    CROSS APPLY dbo.fnParseStringTSQL(y.StringCSV, ',') AS fn
)
SELECT   DISTINCT ID,
         STUFF(
                (
                 SELECT  ',' + REMOVE
                 FROM    cte_Remove AS t2
                 WHERE   t2.ID = t1.ID
                         FOR XML PATH('')
                ),1,1,'') AS col2
FROM     cte_Remove  AS t1
```

**Cleanup Test Data:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#temp') > 0
    DROP TABLE #temp
```